# Breadth First Search controlled by edge number in networkx?

Tags: networkx

I know the networkx could provide the breadth-first search (bfs) results based on the control of depth. I am wondering is there a workaround so I can control the result with the number of edges? For example, I hope to get 10 edges around a node *i* by bfs. But I don't know what depth it could be.

The bfs controlled by the depth is something like

```
bfs = nx.bfs_edges(G, source=i, depth_limit=5)
```

I hope to use a function something like

```
bfs = nx.bfs_edges(G, source=i, number=k)
```

As I hope to find all the edges around a node. So it looks like the `nx.edge_bfs` is a better option? This function returns all the edges currently. Could we modify it somehow? I hope the source node can be located as center as possible, i.e., the yield edges could evenly around the source node.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code of `nx.edge_bfs`, it looks like this function itself returns an iterator which yields the edges surround the source node one by one. And it basically returns the surrounding edges like a circle.

It could be better if someone could confirm this. Here is the source [link](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.edgebfs.edge_bfs.html)